# I am trying to write a query in mongodb using and or together. How to write as one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using and or together and I want to write the query as one, how do I achieve that?

```
router.get('/find/:from/:to', async (req, res)=>{

    let mymessages = []

    try {
        const messages = await Message.find( { $and: [ { from: req.params.from }, { to: req.params.to }, {fromshow: true} ] } )
        const message = await Message.find( { $and: [ { from: req.params.to }, { to: req.params.from },{toshow: true} ] } )

        messages.map(item => mymessages.push(item))
        message .map(item => mymessages.push(item))

        return res.status(200).send(mymessages)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(201).send('something went wrong')
    }
})
```

Comment: Please provide an input and output example. How is your schema and what is your finallity?

Comment: The code given here only has `and`. Where do you like to put an `or`?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({
  "$and": [
    { email:req.params.email },
    { "$or": [
        { email: "sampleValueOne" },
        { email: "sampleValueTwo" }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```